# NSAttributedText font size changes according to the UILabel width

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I have created a `NSAttributedString` in this way

```
attribute3=[
          NSForegroundColorAttributeName: innercircleColor,
          NSFontAttributeName:UIFont.init(name: "Bariol", size: 18.0)!]

attriType=NSAttributedString.init(string: type, attributes: attribute3)
lblType.setAttributedText(attriType)
```

But according to my `UILabel` size, in iPhone 5s this attributed text is coming outside the UILabel. How can I make the attributed text font size  fit to the `UILabel` width

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290234/nsattributedstring-ignores-autoshrink-and-numberoflines-for-uilabel-ios-6 ?

Answer (score -1):

What you want is the `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` property on the `UILabel`. It will auto size the `Font` to fit the frame.

You can also set the number of lines to use to set the text using the `numberOfLines` property and also the minimum size the font should scale to using the `minimumFontSize` property.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uilabel/1620546-adjustsfontsizetofitwidth

Comment: I'm not sure haven't tested with attributed text. It should. Otherwise why not just set the font property directly on the UILabel since font size is now handled automatically?